# React-Leaflet polygons are not being re-rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet

I'm trying to make dynamic polygons by using the react's state, but leaflet polygons are not being re-rendered.

The target is to create a polygon that the user creates clicking in the map.

```
class SimpleExample extends React.Component {
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    positions: [[51.505, -0.09]]
  };
}

addPosition = (e) => {
  const {positions} = this.state
  console.log('Adding positions', positions)
  positions.push([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng])
  this.setState({positions})
}

render() {
    console.log('Should render new positions', this.state.positions)
    const staticPositions = [[51.505, -0.09], [51.4958128370432, -0.10728836059570314], [51.49602657961649, -0.09956359863281251]]
  return (
    <Map 
      center={[51.505, -0.09]} 
      onClick={this.addPosition}
      zoom={13} 
      >
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url='http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
      />
      <Polygon positions={this.state.positions} color="blue" />
      <Polygon positions={staticPositions} color="red" />
      <Polyline positions={this.state.positions} />
    </Map>
  );
}
}
```

Please checkout this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/cesargdm/j2g4ktsg/1/

Comment: can you give more details about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sure, just want to create a polygon that the user creates, clicking in the map.
This is the user clicks in the map, and the coordinates are saved on the state, with this the polygon gets its coordinates.

Comment: Edgar Enriquez :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy this in **jsfiddle** and it should work. Hope it helps.

I have the initial state to an empty array so your first click decides where you start drawing your `<Polygon>`, of course you can use an initial coordinate, that's totally up to you.

Using an arrow function `(prevState)  => {}` you can properly update the state depending on your "previous state", here we're taking the new coordinates and using `concat()` to add it to our `positions` state.

You can find more information about updating the state [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html).

```
const React = window.React;
const { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup, Polygon } = window.ReactLeaflet;

class SimpleExample extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      positions: []
    };
  }

  addPosition = (e) => {
    const newPos = [e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng];
    this.setState(prevState => (
      {
        positions: prevState.positions.concat([newPos])
      }
    ));
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <Map 
        center={[51.505, -0.09]} 
        onClick={this.addPosition}
        zoom={13}>
        <TileLayer attribution='&copy; <ahref="http://osm.org/copyright">
          OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url='http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
        />
        <Polygon positions={this.state.positions} color="blue" />
      </Map>
    );
  }
 }
 window.ReactDOM.render(<SimpleExample />, 
  document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: Thanks! I see that the only thing that I needed to change is the statements inside of addPosition, but I cannot understand why my original code didn't worked ._.